# Error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

Tags: c#, methods, arguments

I've looked through the other answers for this question, but I honestly don't know enough about coding to understand what they're saying. I'm in an intro class and know the bare minimum. I'm supposed to make a car price calculator, using methods to find out which specifications were chosen to get the total price for the car, but keep receiving the error in the tile:

> There is no argument given that corresponds to the required formal parameter

My code is:

```
    double totalPrice = 0.0;
    //Add each cost
    totalPrice += getBasePrice();
    totalPrice += getTransmissionPrice();
    totalPrice += getWheelsPrice();
    totalPrice += getAccessoriesPrice();
    //Calculate tax
    totalPrice += getTax(totalPrice);
    //Display Cost
    lblPriceOutput.Text = totalPrice.ToString("C");
}

public double getBasePrice(double typeChoice)
{
    typeChoice = 0;
    if (rdCar.Checked)
    {
        typeChoice = 19150;
    }
    else if (rdTruck.Checked)
    {
        typeChoice = 29475;
    }
    else if (rdSUV.Checked)
    {
         typeChoice = 30595;
    }
    else if (rdMinivan.Checked)
    {
       typeChoice = 28155;
    }
    return typeChoice;
}
```

Comment: You need to pass double value to the `totalPrice += getBasePrice()`. For example. `totalPrice += getBasePrice(23000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Error: There is no argument given that corresponds to the required
>   formal parameter

Error occurs here:

```
 totalPrice += getBasePrice();
```

**why ?**

Because the method `getBasePrice(double typeChoice)` expects a value of type double to be passed in whenever the method is invoked.

**How to solve the issue ?**

you can resolve it by passing in some data but **MUST** be of type double.

Example :

```
 double myValue = 45.67;
 totalPrice += getBasePrice(myValue);
```

Currently, I am unaware of what specific data you want to pass into the method parameter. However, the solution above solves that issue, so all you have to do is pass the correct data to the method.

**UPDATE**

it seems that all you want to do is invoke the method `getBasePrice()` in order to get the corresponding value(s) within the method. In such situation, I'd suggest that you remove the method parameter and return the value depending on which button is clicked.

Example :

```
public double getBasePrice()
{
     double typeChoice = 0;
     if (rdCar.Checked)
     {
        typeChoice = 19150;
     }
     else if (rdTruck.Checked)
     {
        typeChoice = 29475;
     }
     else if (rdSUV.Checked)
     {
        typeChoice = 30595;
     }
     else if (rdMinivan.Checked)
     {
        typeChoice = 28155;
     }
     return typeChoice;
 }
```

Comment: The issue is that I can't just put a value there, the value depends on what button is chosen. That's why I have the second half, to decide which value should be inputted based on selection... so I don't know what I can put in the parenthesis to make that work.

Comment: @MakaylaMuir You can't say that the decision in which the value of the parameter that's passed in depends on the code that is within the method. If that's the case you'll never invoke the method. In that case I suggest you remove the method parameter.

Comment: @MakaylaMuir based on your comment I will re-update my answer and provide an alternative to achieving your task.

Comment: @MakaylaMuir I have updated my answer to match what you have just told me. The code under "UPDATE" should work and won't give any errors.

Comment: @MakaylaMuir if it has solved your problem i would really appreciate it if you mark the answer as accepted. Thanks.

Comment: The code under update is missing a declaration for the variable. Ie missing `var typeChoice = 0.0d;` or `double typeChoice = 0;`. Also since these are prices, they'd be better as `decimal`, but that's outside of the scope of the question

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Thanks for letting me know . I will update it now. Really appreciate it.